# Green's function existence vs explicit description

Tags: mathematical-physics, greens-functions

Are there examples in physics where the mere *existence* of a Green's function on some domain (for some PDE) has useful applications?  Or is it true that in literally all applications of Green's functions, an explicit description is what is useful and what physicists care about?

Also note that by existence I implicitly mean at the very least some kind of useful bounds (such as pointwise or $L^p$ or Sobolev space bounds...)